# HTML5 validation not working when jQuery included

Tags: jquery, html

So I have a html5 required input field that works fine when I omit the following jQuery confirmation alert...

```
$(".acal-confirm").click(function(){

  if($(this).val() == 'delete'){
    if (!confirm("Delete all positions for this day?")){
      return false;
    }
  }

  if($(this).val() == 'publish'){
    if (!confirm("Publish all positions for this day?")){
      return false;
    }
  }

  if($(this).val() == 'draft'){
    if (!confirm("Save all positions for this day as a draft?")){
      return false;
    }
  }

});
```

...When I include it the confirmation alert appears as expected, but if the input field is blank, the html5 validation is no longer triggered.

The html it is linked to (which is wrapped in a form tag)...

```
<button name="submit" type="submit" value="draft" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg acal-confirm" title="Do not make available publically">Save draft</button>
<button name="submit" type="submit" value="publish" style="margin-left:10px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg acal-confirm" title="Save and publish the positions publically">Publish</button>
<button name="submit" type="submit" value="delete" style="margin-left:10px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg acal-confirm" title="Delete the positions for this day">Delete day</button>
```

What is causing this to happen? Thanks.

Comment: `return false` breaks the default action, that's HTML5 validation. Use `onsubmit` event instead, and you don't need a `return false` if you use HTML validation, the form will never be submitted without javascript if the required fields are not filled

Comment: Ok, thanks. I ended up putting it in a jQuery submit function, which is also an onsubmit event I guess. The confirm call was not to confirm the missing field, but rather to confirm the action of the user upon successful validation. I hope this is what you meant. The 'return false' then cancels the submit if the user changes their mind.

Comment: Oh, I also managed to do `if($(':focus').val() == 'delete'){
    return confirm("Delete all positions for this day?");
  }
` to be more concise.

Comment: I can make a simple script to show you how the html5 validation works and how you can implement it with your logic. Let me some time, I'm on work right now, but I can help you soon.

Comment: Ok, thanks. No hurry though :)

Comment: Answer provided! Tell me if you have any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really simple example of how HTML5 validation works. It works out of the box. You only need to set `required` attribute on required fields and the form will be submitted only if all form is valid to submit. In the following example, I make use of jQuery, but validation needs vanilla javascript, it's because I write `$(this)[0]`, to get the DOM element and not the jQuery object.

```js
//Listen the buttons (its type is not submit!)
$('input[type=button]').on('click', function(ev) {
  var action = $(this).val();
  if (confirm("Are you sure to perform "+action+"?")) {
    // force the submit since there is not a submit button
    $('#myForm').trigger('submit'); 
  }
  // we don't need an else, nor return false! We only submit if it's confirmed 
});

// Listen to the submit event, so when it's the form submitted we can know it
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  // checkValidity() returns true if the form will be send, and false if not
  alert("Form will be submitted?: "+$(this)[0].checkValidity());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="myForm">
  Name: <input type="text" required><br>
  Email: <input type="email" required><br>
  <input type="button" value="First action">
  <input type="button" value="Second action">
  <input type="button" value="Third action">
</form>
```

It's all! You don't need nothing more. There are a lot of methods and properties to manage validation, but with this you can achieve what you want. Imagine your code like this:

```
<!-- FIRST CHANGE THE TYPE TO button -->
<button name="submit" type="button" value="draft" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg acal-confirm" title="Do not make available publically">Save draft</button>
<button name="submit" type="button" value="publish" style="margin-left:10px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg acal-confirm" title="Save and publish the positions publically">Publish</button>
<button name="submit" type="button" value="delete" style="margin-left:10px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg acal-confirm" title="Delete the positions for this day">Delete day</button>
```

And JS:

```
$(".acal-confirm").click(function(){

  if($(this).val() == 'delete'){
    if (confirm("Delete all positions for this day?")){
      $('form').attr('action', '/url/to/delete').trigger('submit');
    }
  }

  if($(this).val() == 'publish'){
    if (confirm("Publish all positions for this day?")){
      $('form').attr('action', '/url/to/publish').trigger('submit');
    }
  }

  if($(this).val() == 'draft'){
    if (confirm("Save all positions for this day as a draft?")){
      $('form').attr('action', '/url/to/save').trigger('submit');
    }
  }

});
```

Tell me if this fits with your requirements. Note the `form.attr('action')` edition, it's to identify what action needs to perform depending on the button you clicked. There are tons of ways to do this, this edition is only an example

Comment: Wow, such a thorough answer. I really appreciate it. Thanks.